# What's the diff btween src/main/resources and src/main/webapp/resources?

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, static-content

I have a Spring MVC 3.0 project, using Maven, generated right from Eclipse's `New -> Project -> Spring Project -> Spring MVC Project`.  However, I see **two** `resources` folders, one directly under src/main and another one level deeper under src/main/webapp.  I guess this is a two part question.:

(a) Under which of the two should my static content (css, js, and imgs) go? and

(b) What, then, is supposed to go under the other one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- (a) In the webapp
- (b) Your java resource files you need to access from the classpath

Comment: (b) generally configuration/propertie files.